# Why does my react state update on component re render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I have the following code:

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(6)
function handleClick() { 
setNumber(5) 
}
...
<Button onClick={handleClick}/>
```

When I click the button, the component displays "5" as desired. But when I close the component and re-open it, it defaults back to "6". Does the set state happen on each re-render automatically? And is there a good way to work around this?

Comment: The issue is using local state versus global state. Local state gets reset as soon as you close the component.

Comment: if you need to "remember" something between renders of this component, considering keeping that in state in a parent component and passing it to the child component as a prop, rather than have it be state in the child. Not saying that's necessarily right though - everything depends on the details of your components and the application you're building with them.

Comment: there was complete section in old react docs - "Lifting state up". Must read for you https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is **using local state versus global state**.

Unfortunately, global state is complicated in React as it needs to keep track of when to rerender.

To do this, you could use `useContext()` and `useReducer()`.

[This tutorial](https://dev.to/eswaraprakash/react-usecontext-and-usereducer-hooks-2pkm) explains it well.

Here is [a working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-cookies-8pqsqk?file=/src/Component1.jsx) on codesandbox.io.

### 1. Create a `GlobalProvider.jsx` file:

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

// Initial state
const globalsInitialState = {
  number: 6
};

// Different actions to update the state
const actions = {
  UPDATE_NUMBER: "UPDATE_NUMBER"
};

// How to update the state
export const globalsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.UPDATE_NUMBER:
      return {
        ...state,
        number: action.newNumber
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

//Context and Provider
export const GlobalsContext = createContext();

export const GlobalsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(globalsReducer, globalsInitialState);

  const value = {
    number: state.number,
    updateNumber: (newNumber) => {
      dispatch({ type: actions.UPDATE_NUMBER, newNumber });
    }
  };

  return (
    <GlobalsContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</GlobalsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

### 2. Wrap your app with the Global Provider.

This makes your global context available to all its children.

```
import { GlobalsProvider } from "./GlobalsProvider";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalsProvider>
      // ...
    </GlobalsProvider>
  );
```

### 3. Use the `GlobalContext` in your component:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { GlobalsContext } from "./GlobalsProvider";

export const Component1 = () => {
  const { number, updateNumber } = useContext(GlobalsContext);

  const handleClick = () => {
    updateNumber(5);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>My number is {number}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Change number to 5</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: surely this will lead to an "invalid hook call" error. Hooks like `useState` can only be called inside components, not in an imported "helper" file.

Comment: @RobinZigmond  Yep:  `Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Comment: If you want to shift state away from the component, unfortunately React's built in state manager is not designed to do that,  but doing what you explain could be done with a 3rd party lib like https://jotai.org/docs/core/use-atom

Comment: Ahh right... Let me look into this...

Comment: @Keith Could you review again?

Comment: I assume this now works (I can't see any obvious errors at first glance), so I've removed the downvote. But as to whether it's actually appropriate for the OP's usecase, we can't possibly know. As I already suggested in my comment on the OP, I'm personally more inclined to reach for state in a parent component, passed to the child as a prop, rather than context. But as I also said, without knowing the OP's actual situation there is no clear "best" or "right" solution.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Fair, I guess SO is a place where you can learn about several different solutions to your problem, right? Maybe add a MVP of passing the state to the component using a prop?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not personally inclined to add an "answer" doing this because I don't think the problem as stated has a single "best answer" so while I personally think it's a "better guess" than what you have, I don't think it's worth my time doing. That's not to criticise your approach too much, but I prefer in this case to express my opinion through comments like those on your answer as well as on the OP.